# Transmission slipping at 90k miles

Tags: automatic-transmission, hyundai, elantra

My 2010 Hyundai Elantra started having transmission slipping issues this year (engine revs, but there is no acceleration during driving). It has 90k miles on it. Took it into a mechanic and they recommended I pretty much junk it at this point.

What options do I have at this point?

[This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/cars/comments/6nu6pn/2010_hyundai_elantra_touring_gls/) says one of the models has 90% failure rate. Is this true for the 2010's, are there known issues? If so, is it something Hyundai would address?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question which is off-topic here.  But it's entirely up to you whether this car is worth fixing or not.  Chances are a replacement transmission is what is needed.  At 90K miles and 12 years old I'd be looking at a rebuilt or even a used transmission.

Comment: Statistical information is not as important as the actual problem of a particular car. However, my experience is once it slips it is going to get worse until rebuilt. The wear debris from the bands, clutches , sprage, whatever has failed, will plug valves etc,  causing other problems. Use it if you can until you junk it or rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

Hyundai is usually pretty good about recalls.  Mechanics are not usually transmission experts, so I'd take it to a good transmission shop around you and get their opinion on it.  Could just be the torque converter, could need a flush and refill, or it could be time for a full rebuild.

Comment: Is there a recall on the transmission? I have not seen one when I went over the recall list.

Comment: With a 90% failure rate I would assume there should be a recall, and Hyundai does reuse engines & transmissions between models to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have warranty on the unit. If not look into the cost of having it rebuilt. Normally getting one from a crashed car is a good choice, but if the product is known for a high failure rate, it just might fail again.

Comment: I bought the car used at 1000 miles, so I don't believe the warranty would apply to me based on https://www.hyundaiusa.com/us/en/assurance/america-best-warranty